# Integrating $\int \frac{x^2}{1+x^5} \, dx $

Tags: integration

I just encountered the following integral 
$$\int \frac{x^2}{1+x^5} \, dx $$
At first it appeared to be simple, but I don't know how to solve it. Please share any ideas.

Comment: [Quite a long closed form....](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=\int{\frac{x^2}{1%2Bx^5}dx})

Comment: **Hint:** [partial fractions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+x%5E2%2F%28x%5E5+%2B+1%29)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This is not looking like partial fraction problem , if you know please tell me how is it solvable through partial fraction.

Comment: You could just integrate the terms one at a time

Comment: Hint: Use partial fractions to change it into 3 fractions. The quadratic ones can be done either by partial fractions over $\Bbb{C}$, or by using a trig substitution. The other one can be done iwth the power rule.

Comment: If you know the antiderivative of $\frac1{1+x^6}$ then use this method: $x^2 = x^4+(x^2-x^4)$, multiply top and bottom of the second integral by $x^3$, set $ x^7-x^5 = \frac18 \left( (8x^7+3x^2)-(8x^5+3x^2)\right)$, divide by $ x^2$, for the first integral, set $y=x^3$, then you're left with the integration of $\frac1{1+x^6}$

Comment: With the integration of $\frac1{x^6+1} $, we just apply the sixth root unity and partial fraction cover up rule.

Answer (score 2):

In this problem, the hard part is the algebra.

\begin{align}
x^5 + 1 & = (x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1) \\[10pt]
& = (x+1)\left(x^2 - 2x\cos\frac\pi5 + 1\right)\left(x^2 - 2x\cos\frac{3\pi}5 + 1\right)
\end{align}

These two quadratic factors are irreducible, as can be seen by the fact that their discriminants are negative.

Next, proceed to partial fractions.  Completing the square, you get
\begin{align}
x^2 -2x\cos\frac\pi 5 +1 & =\left( x^2 - 2x\cos\frac\pi 5 + \cos^2\frac\pi5\right) + \sin^2 \frac\pi5 \\[10pt]
& = \left( x - \cos\frac\pi5 \right)^2 +\sin^2\frac\pi 5.
\end{align}

If you have $\dfrac{Ax+B}{\left( x - \cos\frac\pi5 \right)^2 +\sin^2\frac\pi 5} \, dx$, you can write it as
\begin{align}
& \frac{A\left(x-\cos\frac\pi5\right)}{\left( x - \cos\frac\pi5 \right)^2 +\sin^2\frac\pi 5}\,dx + \frac{B + A\cos\frac\pi 5}{\left( x - \cos\frac\pi5 \right)^2 +\sin^2\frac\pi 5}\,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\frac 1 2\,du}{u} + \frac{B + A\cos\frac\pi 5}{\left( x - \cos\frac\pi5 \right)^2 +\sin^2\frac\pi 5}\,dx
\end{align}
The first term yields a logarithm and the second an arctangent.

Moral: In this probelm, the hard part is the algebra.

So **how did I get $\pi/5$ and $3\pi/5$**?

The point is that $x^5+1=0$ iff $x^5 = -1$, and the $5$th roots of $-1$ are $\cos\dfrac\pi5 + i\sin\dfrac\pi 5$ and other points on the circle differing from that by a fifth of a circle, i.e. $2\pi/5$ radians.  One of those points is $-1$, and that's where $(x+1)$ came from.  Two of those points are $\cos\frac\pi5 \pm i\sin\frac\pi5$, and two are $\cos\frac {3\pi}5\pm i\sin\frac{3\pi}5$.  So
$$
\left(x - \cos\frac\pi 5 - i \sin\frac\pi5\right)\left(x - \cos\frac\pi 5 + i \sin\frac\pi5\right) = \left(x^2 - 2x\cos\frac\pi5+1\right).
$$